# Moving towards a point script not working

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I've come up with an extremely basic script to move towards a point but it does not seem to be working. the commented code that's in my script was working, but my new function is not working. Could somebody please tell me why this script is not working.

```
public int _x = 0;
public int _y = 0;
Bitmap _scratch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

public void move_to(int fx, int fy, int tx, int ty){
    if(fx<tx){
        fx+=1;
    }else
    if(fx>fy){
        fx-=1;
    }
    if(fy<ty){
        fy+=1;
    }else
    if(fy>fy){
        fy-=1;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, _x, _y, null);
    //_y+=1;
   // _x+=1;
    move_to(_x, _y, 50, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
public void move_to(int fx, int fy, int tx, int ty){
    if(fx<tx){
        fx+=1;
    }else
    if(fx>tx){
        fx-=1;
    }
    if(fy<ty){
        fy+=1;
    }else
    if(fy>ty){
        fy-=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for pointing that out, but if you do read the script, that little mistake doesnt make a difference. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In move_to you change fx and fy. Maybe you want to change _x and _y instead.